# Running ubuntu side by side with windows and OSX

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, apple

i have a Apple macbook air currently running OS X 10.10 and Windows 7 HP with bootcamp, during the installation of windows i messed up a couple times badly enough that i had to factory reset my computer, i have since fixed that issue and the the 2 OSs are running in harmony. I have now realized that in the event that something happens to my internal hard drive i need a external OS to fix them (other than the apple internet recovery).

What i am asking for help with is step by step instructions on how to install Ubuntu on to a external hard drive and run it from there and only from there. I am not a computer expert so to say but i do now many things on how to operate computers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this exact thing before.

Make sure your external drive is plugged in.

Insert your ubuntu disk or flash drive.

boot the mac and select to boot from disk or flash drive.

When you get to the installation type, choose "something else".

select the external drive from the partition wizard .. it may be labeled as sdb for example.

click on change.

format as ext4 and select "/" to install on the root directory. (you may also tweak your patition size if you do not wish to use the entire hard drive)

IMPORTANT - make sure you selct install the boot loader at the begining of external hard drive and NOT on sda (this allows the mac to recognize the external drive as a bootable device and also does not mess up your mac)

after that click on "install now"

then continue on with the installation as per normal

after it is complete and rebooted you should be able to select linux as a boot option.

Remember important, the bootloader must be installed on the external drive, not on the internal drive.

Comment: OK sounds great, but i already made a partition where i want to install ubuntu on, is it possible to do that with out deleting the other partions on the external drive?

Comment: yes the partition wizard on the install disk will recognize all the partitions. you just need to select the right one.